# Read recursively nested pyspark files

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, schema

I am trying to extract all the partitioned parquet files of an object, get the schema of all the extracted files and create a dataframe out of it.

I tried using the below command but it outputs a schema rather than collecting all the files.

```
spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true").parquet("s3://path1/path2")
```

This is the first time I am using this command, any suggestions on collecting the parquet files from the above command so that i can extract their individual schemas.

Comment: the aforementioned will give you a single dataframe, not multiple dataframes. so, there'll be one schema only - the created dataframe's schema. what y're trying to achieve is best possible using pandas by reading few rows from each data file. -- to see the df out of that code, add `.show()` at the end. also see - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#recursive-file-lookup